# Rust lightningcss minify

Tags: rust

Trying to figure out how to use minify from `lightningcss`. Here's my code

```
let fs = FileProvider::new();
let mut bundler = Bundler::new(&fs, None, ParserOptions::default());
let stylesheet = bundler.bundle(Path::new("./assets/css/global.css")).unwrap();
stylesheet.minify(MinifyOptions::default());
println!("{}", stylesheet.to_css(PrinterOptions::default()).unwrap().code);
```

If I try to print the unwrapped version of the minified output that is empty.

taken more from here https://docs.rs/lightningcss/1.0.0-alpha.34/lightningcss/stylesheet/struct.StyleSheet.html

And the question: how do I use the minify output?

Comment: I encourage you to [file an issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/lightningcss/issues) on their repository asking your question. Given the release version is `-alpha.34`, they may still have growing pains plaguing them as they move to release their Rust code for public use.

Comment: Good point @kmdreko -- done here https://github.com/parcel-bundler/lightningcss/issues/297

Comment: Question has been answered in the GH issue above.